# H2 + Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, база-данных, java

Здравствуйте. Хочу прикрутить к
приложению СУБД H2. Скачал jar,
положил в корневой каталог проекта. Той
информации по работе с H2, что я
нагуглил как-то маловато. Есть методы
для работы с ней, но вопрос в том как
собсно создать в ней базу, помимо того
что создать какой-нибудь мелкий проект и
работать через консоль или Swing, а
потом переносить в существующий?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно, с любой embedded базой работа ведется так:

Берем какого-нить гуйного клиента для H2 [фтыкать тут](http://h2database.com/html/links.html#tools), создаем там бд, таблицы, индексы, если надо и данные. Переносим файл БД в проект, далее подключаемся через JDBC или там через Hibernate и работаем

P.S. Док по H2 мне кажется более [чем достаточно](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html)